# Gradle Xpp3 error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error when performing a gradle build for a release version.

> Error: xpp3 defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by
>   Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative
>   libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for
>   httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging
>   the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

I tried to exclude `httpclient` but that didn't help.
In the debug version its working but in the release version it gives me this error.

I was using Android Asynchronous Http Client but removing it also didn't resolve the error.

My gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.corona.corona"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.6.0'
    implementation 'io.github.rockerhieu:emojicon:1.4.2'
    implementation 'io.github.rockerhieu:emojiconize:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.4.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get any crashes in production environment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems problem comes from Smack library. Try excluding xpp3 module.

```
configurations {
    all {
        ...
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
}
```

Comment: @joseantelo can you please also help me tell that whether excluding xpp3, httpclient and commons-logging, how does any places in the code which needs to use these will use it. Basically, does smack not crashes your app if you exclude these.Does it work in production environment ?

Comment: @abhishekranjan Excluded module xpp3 is already included in Android so Smack library will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to exclude xpp3 from the smack library with:

```
implementation ('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}

implementation ('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}

implementation ('org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

or, like @jose-antelo answer, you can use the following code to remove xpp3 from all of your dependencies:

```
configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Comment: will this affect the app in production environment? Is there a chance that the app will crash due to this in production

Comment: @abhishekranjan: This won't affect the app in production. I use the above in one of my production app.