# Not able to generate signed apk? [DuplicatePlatformClasses error occured]

Tags: android, http, android-studio-3.0

I am getting this error,

Error: xpp3 defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

while generating signed apk. How can i solve this problem. Please help me!!

App Gradle,

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.casperon.app.rydepass"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 17
    versionName "4.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
compile project(':CountryCodePicker')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.7.0'
compile 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.2.2'
compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.2'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.5.0'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.crazy1235:RichEditText:v2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
  //noinspection DuplicatePlatformClasses
 /* compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'*/
'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6'

configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48746294/6021469

Comment: try using support library version 26.0.0 or above

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Same issue.

Comment: The error message gives pretty detailed advice how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
   configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}
```

Comment: Not help. I get compile error: import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;

Comment: @ana will the app not be able to use xpp3 module wherever it needs to, and further will the app not crash in production due to this reason. Can you please explain. I am experiencing the same issue and I wanted to know that how can excluding xpp3 affect my app (rightly or in a wrong way)?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Apache library had been used in whole project and I couldn't exclude this library. Today I tried using jar file instead and it worked. You can download apache http library jar files from here:
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.httpcomponents